# PHP 7 can't connect to database

Tags: database, mariadb, centos7

I update my PHP version to 7 on my Centos7 server.

With my sequel pro I can connect to my database from everywhere but with normal mysql connection in php I get an Access denied. Someone had the same problem and solved it?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: u can see the error if u visit codeanarchy.net

Comment: "Access denied" usually means that `$username` was not `GRANTed` access to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It is very clear from the error... you are using wrong username and password or hostname.

Are you sure servername for mysql service is installed is **euve102326.serverprofi24.de**

Comment: yes everything work correct when i am not using php, i can connect with every program like sequel pro or mysql workbench etc. only with php it is not working and i think its the problem of php 7

Comment: database version is MySQL 5.5.44-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

OK i fixed it the Problem was the user 'wp'@'%' than it don't take the password i don't know why but now i delete this user and add 'wp'@'localhost' and it works only with password